# Java Iterating Over a TreeMap - incompatible types

Tags: java, iterator, iteration, treemap

I have the following collection:

```
private Map <String, Staff> staff;
```

Implemented as a TreeMap:

```
staff = new TreeMap <String, Staff> ();
```

I need to iterate over the values in this map, but when I try the following code I'm getting an incompatible types compilation error. I can't understand why this is; the values in my map are Staff objects and

```
it.HasNext()
```

should be returning them to be stored in the staffMember variable, which should be fine to my knowledge?? Help much appreciated.

```
Collection <Staff> staffList = staff.values(); 
         Iterator it = staffList.iterator ();
         while ((isJobAssigned = false) ||it.hasNext())
         {
             Staff staffMember = it.next(); 
             if ((staffMember instanceof Typist) && (jobType.equalsIgnoreCase("Typist")))
             {
                 newJob.setJobState ("Assigned");
                 staffMember.setState("Working");
                 return newJon.getJobNo() + " Staff allocated: " + staffMember.getName () + ", ID: " + staffMember.getId();
                }
```

Comment: Using `instanceof` is a sign a code smell. Consider having an `enum` of staff member types and a case switch on the enum. The `Staff` class can have an `abstract` method that force any implementation to return its type. An even better solution would be a Visitor Pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I've read a few times now about the abuse of instanceof and the fact that it's a bad code smell, so will aim to avoid in future projects and refactor as you suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a raw `Iterator`. Either you need to cast to `Staff` the `Object` returned by `it.next()` or use a generic `Iterator`.

Using a raw iterator :

```
Staff staffMember = (Staff)it.next();
```

Using a generic iterator (I recommend this version) :

```
Iterator<Staff> it = staffList.iterator();
Staff staffMember = it.next();  //you can keep this
```

Comment: Do not use a raw iterator if you can specify the type, be type safe. +1

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your recommended solution and it works perfectly. I'll do some research on generics to make sure I understand this fully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Why aren't you using:

```
for (Staff st : staff.values()){
 // do your stuff
 if(st instanceof Typist) break;   
}
```

Comment: Though it does not answer the question, it is definitely a better solution.

Comment: I want to stop iterating when we reach the first member of staff that matches the job type, so I thought a while loop would be better to do that?

Comment: Why not break? I edited my answer with a condition a copied from you question but the general point here is the use of break to exit the loop.

Comment: Because I am a novice :-) That's a good point now you've explained. I was just sticking to the hard and fast rules of FOR = iterate over the whole collection, WHILE = indefinite iteration. That's a neat technique though and certainly tidies up this code.